# Rotating catalina.out with timestamp format using logrotate. like catalina.$date.out

Tags: linux, logrotate, tomcat

I am using `logrotate` to rotate `catalina.out`, but after rotation the filename is like `catalina.out.1.gz`.

I want it to rotate the file with a timestamp in its name, like: `catalina-2015-08-10-2337.out.gz`. 
How can I do this with `logrotate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use **dateext** option. Here is notes from man page for logrotate:

```
 dateext
              Archive  old versions of log files adding a date extension like YYYYMMDD instead of simply adding a number. The extension may be
              configured using the dateformat and dateyesterday options.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my logrotate configuration in these cases:

```
/path/to/tomcat/log/catalina.out {
    daily
    dateext
    rotate 3650
    missingok
    notifempty
    compress
    copytruncate       
}
```